# Hotkey for "This PC"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-10, hotkeys

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in Windows 7 the explorer opens in the view which is called "This PC" in Windows 10. In Windows 10 instead the "Quick access" view is opened. Is there a possibility to access the "This PC" in Windows 10 quickly using only keyboard commands? I also like the "Quick access" view so I'm not so sure if I want to permanently set "This PC" to the default view when the explorer is opened? But is that even possible? What different possibilities are there?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can quickly and easily change it:

1. Click **View** in the menu of File Explorer
2. Click **Options** at the right side of the ribbon, then **Change folder and search options** (or simply click the icon above **Options**)
3. In the dropdown menu next to **Open File Explorer to:** select **This PC**
4. Click OK.

[image]

[image]

> I also like the "Quick access" view so I'm not so sure if I want to permanently set "This PC" to the default view when the explorer is opened

In that case you have two options:

1. Get used to simply clicking **Quick access** in the navigation pane of File Explorer
2. Pin **Quick access** to the Start menu and assign a custom keyboard shortcut to it:

   1. Right-click **Quick access** in File Explorer and click **Pin to Start**
   2. Right-click **Quick access** in the Start menu and click **Open file location**
   3. Right-click the shortcut for Quick access and click **Properties**
   4. Assign a keyboard shortcut

As for keyboard shortcuts, you can assign shortcuts of the following forms:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>(key)</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>(key)</kbd>
- Function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> etc.)

If you only press a letter, then the first form is automatically used.
If you select a keyboard shortcut that is used for other purposes (such as <kbd>F1</kbd>), then your shortcut will either not work, or the functionality of <kbd>F1</kbd> will be overridden by your shortcut.

Comment: Are all those shortcuts which you can assign using your strategy of the form Ctrl+Alt+Letter? And are all shortcuts of this form free when start with a new installed system?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain You can assign shortcuts of the form Ctrl+Alt+Key, Ctrl+Shift+Key (hold down Ctrl and Shift to do this), Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Key (again hold down all keys), and function keys (F1, F2 etc., just make sure to choose one that's not reserved for other purposes).

Comment: Can Windows shoe me a list of all combinations which are already set as global hotkey for some action?

Comment: You can check out the lists of keyboard shortcuts for Windows 10 here: [Keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Thank you for that list. But what I meant is a list of current hotkeys on the running system. So it should include my own hotkeys.

Comment: I believe you can use some sort of software to detect that, however I don't know any, so you're probably better off searching Google for it.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain – there is relatively unoccupied key space for global hot keys in combination Ctrl+Alt+Shift+key. You can put your own hotkeys there. Anything else (Ctrl+Alt, Ctrl+Shift, Alt+Shift) is pretty frequently used by applications (think of Word, Excel, ...). Do you have AppsKey on your keyboard? Or CapsLock you don't use? I can help you turn it into another key modifier, because I'm doing that already. The key it is AutoHotKey tool. If you want more information, just post a new question and @-notify me about it.

Comment: God bless you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Probably very late to answer But I was also in the same boat.

one more alternative to @FastEthernet suggestion is:

pin "This PC" to the task bar. and use `Win` + `{number}` to open it quickly.

What is {number}? Position of pinned "This PC" on task bar.

Comment: Are you sure about "Win"+"Nbr"? I've just tried with some numbers, but nothing happened (and I do have some items, pinned on my taskbar).

Answer (score -1):

Win+{Number} works for me. The finding is I cannot pin "This PC" directly to Taskbar. I have to pin it to START first, then right click on it -> More -> Pin to taskbar. A PC icon will show on taskbar then I move it to first position in Taskbar. Win + 1 will open "This PC" perfectly.

Comment: downvote but no reason given.