# Pin folder to Start

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, start-menu

As I learned in [FastEthernet's answer](https://superuser.com/a/972151/489030) it is possible to pin *Quick access* to *Start* in order to set a shortcut. Now I tried to pin other folders to *Start*. But that option isn't part of the context menu when I right click them. Is there another way?

Comment: Are you **sure**? In the file explorer, I opened my C drive, right-clicked on a random folder and on the Windows folder, and both of them included `Pin to Start` as an option, immediately above the `Send to` option. `Pin to Quick access` was not adjacent.

Comment: @Dane Sorry, you are absolutely right. I've found it. Much further above there is the entry `Pin to Quick access` and I was looking for `Pin to Start` in this region.